# io.on connection not getting fired in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to implement socket.io in my nodejs app. When i try

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

I am not getting any console logs.

When i try

```
server = app.listen(port);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

I am getting infinite `a user connected` logs.

In front end my implementation is

```
<body onload="loaded()">
<script>
function loaded(){
   var socket = io();
}
</script>
```

What is wrong i am doing. I saw one method

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

but i want to use express variable in

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

which i will not get in that implementation.

Comment: I think you can get the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444667/socket-io-connect-event-not-firing

Comment: @Yoginth it has the same implementation which i am trying to avoid
```var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);```